# How to create drawable folder for Nexus -5X device?

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications, drawable, nexus-5

I have worked with Firebase Notification. Here i have set the notification image . But Nexus 5x image device does not show the image when i receive the notification. Kindly please let me know how to create drawable folder for Nexus 5x device, or otherwise is there anyway for displaying image on Nexus 5x device.

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
```

Comment: check whether image is present in drawable xxxhdpi

Comment: Is `app_icon` an actual notification icon (i.e., alpha channel only)?

Comment: It is there with in xxxhdpi. @siddhesh

Comment: paste that image in different folders hdpi,xxhdpi,

Comment: I have app_icon image within hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi , still i'm having problem with Nexus 5x can't get the app_icon image. @siddhesh

Comment: open that image in android studio from each folder check whether it is same  as in all folders it happens with me sometimes my all folder have same image but in one of the folder i have that image with same name but different image

Comment: or else change your icon to 32*32 dims png only

Comment: ok, i will try and let you know. @siddhesh

Comment: Sorry it's not working @siddhesh, Is there any drawable folder for Nexuz 5x device?

Comment: Let me remind you that the method setSmallIcon adds the icon to show up on the status bar. If you want to display an icon on the notification view, you should use setLargeIcon. Also, can you please add a picture of your icon and a screenshot of how the notifcation shows on the screen?